# Copy Files and Folders Checking for existence

Tags: c#, file-copying

(Newer to C#)

I have an application that I have built that copies files and folders from one location to another. I originally had issues with folders. For some reason, it would try to copy the file over without creating the directory. I solved that by adding a second section to check if the folder exists and if not create it. I am sure there is a better way to handle this, but this is what worked, so I went with it. The ultimate goal is this.

1. check if the file/folder exists in the destination location and is older than the source file/folder
2. If the file/folder doesn't exist, copy it over. If the file/folder is older than the source, copy it over.
3. If the file folder exists in the destination and not in the source (indicating it was deleted) move the file from the destination location to an archive folder

Below is what I have so far, and it does everything but what is described in #3 above. Any ideas in regards to how I can add the ability from #3 into the functionality, or simplify the copy of files and create the folder if it doesn't exist would be much appreciated.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace FileCopy
{
    class Program
    {
        public static string dtnow = DateTime.Now.ToString("mmdd_hhmm");
        public static string watch_path = string.Empty;
        public static string copy_path = string.Empty;
        public static string final_copy_path = string.Empty;
        public static string log_folder = @"C:\copylogs";
        //public static string log_file = "copy_log";
        public static string log_file = Path.Combine(log_folder + "\\copy_log" + dtnow + ".txt");
        public static int newer_count = 0;
        public static int skip_count = 0;
        public static int copy_count = 0;
        public static int totalcount = 0;
        public static int currentcount = 0;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            if (args == null || args.Length < 2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid Syntax");
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                watch_path = args[0];
                copy_path = args[1];
                log_start_Check(log_folder,log_file);
                CopyFolder(watch_path, copy_path);
                finalcount_statement();
            }

        }

// Log Folder check and creation
        public static void log_start_Check(string log_folder, string log_file)
        {
            Console.Write("Checking Log Folder: ");
            if (!Directory.Exists(log_folder))
            {
                try
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(log_folder);
                    Console.WriteLine("Created!");
                }
                catch (Exception error)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Unable to Create Directory" + error);
                    return;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exists");
            }
            Console.Write("Checking Log File: ");
            //Console.WriteLine(log_file);
            if (!File.Exists(log_file))
            {
                try
                {
                    File.Create(log_file);
                    Console.WriteLine("Created!");
                }
                catch (Exception error)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Unable to Create file" + error);
                    return;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exists");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }

// Copy Folder Functions
        static public void CopyFolder(string sourceFolder, string destFolder)
        {
            try
            {
                if (!Directory.Exists(destFolder))
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(destFolder);
                totalcount = Directory.GetFiles(sourceFolder, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Count();
                string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(sourceFolder);
                totalcount = files.Length;
                foreach (string file in files)
                {
                    string name = Path.GetFileName(file);
                    FileInfo source_info = new FileInfo(file);
                    string dest = Path.Combine(destFolder, name);
                    FileInfo dest_info = new FileInfo(dest);
                    if (File.Exists(dest))
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            if (source_info.LastWriteTime > dest_info.LastWriteTime)
                            {
                                //Console.Write("\r" + currentcount + " of " + totalcount + " Completed     ");
                                Console.ResetColor();
                                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
                                File.Copy(file, dest, true);
                                Console.Write("\rFile Newer, File Copied " + dest + "                         ");
                                Console.ResetColor();
                                newer_count++;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                //Console.Write("\r" + currentcount + " of " + totalcount + " Completed     ");
                                Console.ResetColor();
                                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                                Console.Write("\r** - File Exists " + dest + "                         ");
                                Console.ResetColor();
                                skip_count++;
                            }                          
                        }
                        catch (Exception error)
                        {
                            error_handling("Error in Application " + error.Message, dest, file);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            //Console.Write("\r"+currentcount + " of " + totalcount + " Completed     ");
                            Console.ResetColor();
                            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                            File.Copy(file, dest, false);
                            Console.Write("\rFile Copied " + dest + "                         ");
                            Console.ResetColor();
                            copy_count++;
                        }
                        catch (Exception error)
                        {
                            error_handling("Error in Application " + error.Message, dest, file);
                        }
                    }
                    currentcount++;
                }
                string[] folders = Directory.GetDirectories(sourceFolder);
                foreach (string folder in folders)
                {
                    string name = Path.GetFileName(folder);
                    string dest = Path.Combine(destFolder, name);
                    CopyFolder(folder, dest);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception error)
            {
                error_handling("Error in Application " + error.Message, null, null);
            }
        }
// Error Handling to add messages to logs
        public static void error_handling(string message, string fileident, string source)
        {
            using (System.IO.StreamWriter myFile = new System.IO.StreamWriter(log_file, true))
            {
                string finalMessage = string.Format("{0}: {1} SOURCE: {3} - DEST: {2}", DateTime.Now, message, fileident, source, Environment.NewLine);
                myFile.WriteLine(finalMessage);
                myFile.Close();
            }
        }
        // Final Statement
        public static void finalcount_statement()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
            Console.WriteLine("Total New Files Copied: " + copy_count);
            Console.WriteLine("Total Newer Files Updated: " + newer_count);
            Console.WriteLine("Total Files Skipped: " + skip_count);
            Console.WriteLine("--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In #3, did you really mean to copy the file, or did you mean to move the file? Is this meant for copying to/from local storage only, or should this optimize for remote copying?

Comment: Yes, I meant to move the file/folder to the archive location.

Comment: Unless I knew otherwise, today, I would first get a complete list of all the directories in the source and destination, and all the files in the source and destination (along with timestamp(s)), then start logging changes to make in a list: Archive any deleted files, Remove any deleted folders, create any missing folders, copy files.  Then I would display what I am about to do based upon the list of things I need to do, then do them.

Comment: that was what I thought of first, but the problem was that we are dealing with terabytes of files.

Comment: What difference does it make the size of the files?  The above would work fine with petabytes of files.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it the same way around, maybe like this:

```
static public void ArchiveCopyFolder(string sourceFolder, string destFolder)
{
    try
    {
        if (!Directory.Exists(sourceFolder))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(archivefolder + destFolder);
            //Copy folder and files
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should use `Path.Combine` instead of `+` when combining paths.

Comment: @DrewNoakes Thank you for the advice. Is there a specific reason that `Path.Combine` is better?

Comment: Sure, I should have explained. If `archiveFolder` doesn't end with a separator (such as `\`) then `+` will create an invalid path. The `Path.Combine` method will make sure that a separator is included in the result.